# Get TFS Work Item/WorkItemID when command called from contextmenu of Resultlist

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, vsx, tfs-workitem

In an extension for visual studio 2013 i placed a commandaction for TFS WorkItem Contextmenu (GUID:ID = {2DC8D6BB-916C-4B80-9C52-FD8FC371ACC2}:0x0206)

the contextmenu entry with my command is available on rightclicking in the background of the work item editor (direct opened single workitem) or in the lower pane of a resultlist where the workitemedior is shown.

**now my problem:**
i only get the workitemid by checking _dte.ActiveDocument.Name (.Fullname) when the command was called from workitemeditor directly (single opened workitem) but not when the queryresult list is in play.

ok, when only workitem is opened:

```
vstfs:///WorkItemTracking/WorkItem/4711
```

but if i call the command from a queryresult in ActiveDocument there is no workitem id in ActiveDocument - only a tfs url guid witch looks like this:

```
vstfs:///WorkItemTracking/Results/76ec1234-0000-00000-1234-f82d48b00000
```

How can i get the id or workitemobject when the command is called from the resultlist? Also multiple Workitems can be selected in the resultlist of a TFS-query - how can i get a list of IDs/Workitems?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a working solution by reverse engineer :)

```
        WorkItemStore service = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        IWorkItemTrackingDocument activeDocument = this.GetActiveDocument();
        IWorkItemDocument workItemDocument = activeDocument as IWorkItemDocument;
        IResultsDocument resultsDocument = activeDocument as IResultsDocument;

        if (workItemDocument != null)
        {
            // Workitem
            Debug.WriteLine("A Workitem: {0}: {1}", workItemDocument.Item.Id, workItemDocument.Item.Title);
        }

        if (resultsDocument != null)
        {
            // Resultlist
            Debug.WriteLine("A Resultlist: IDs {0}", resultsDocument.SelectedItemIds);
        }
```